# PHP Script Takes So Much Time More Than Expected

Tags: java, php, loops, benchmarking

My PHP script takes 32 seconds, while doing the same thing using Java takes ~2 milliseconds and 200 milliseconds using golang.

Why the PHP script takes so much time? I know PHP is an interpreted language and it executes much more instructions inside the interpreter than we saw, but this code is so simple, are there any other reasons there?

env info:

```
php version: PHP 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.19 (cli), Zend Engine v3.4.0
hardware: 15G RAM, 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11800H @ 2.30GHz
software: ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Windows WSL2.
```

php Code:

```
<?php
 
     function test(int $max, int $start) {
 
         $time_start = microtime(true);
         while ($start < $max) {
             $start = $start+1;
         }
 
         $time_end = microtime(true);
 
         //dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes otherwise seconds
         $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start);
 
         //execution time of the script
         print('Total Execution Time: '.$execution_time.' Seconds \n');
     }
 
     test(1000000000, 0);
```

Java code:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
  
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import javax.swing.*;
  
  
  class Benchmark {
 
      public static void main(String args[]) {
 
          int max = 1000000000;
          int index = 0;
 
          long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
 
          while(index < max) {
              index++;
          }
 
          long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
          System.out.println("Elapsed Time in millseconds: "+ (end-start));
          System.out.println("index: "+ index);
 
      }
  }
```

Comment: Java can almost certainly figure out how to eliminate the loop entirely by just setting `index = max`.

Answer (score 0):

While I suspect our systems are similar in power and I'm on an older (7.1) version of PHP in which I get:

```
Total Execution Time: 9.6295697689056 Seconds
```

Which seems totally reasonable for a scripting language for 1 billion operations. I suspect newer versions of PHP are faster.

So my answer is more of an explanation and without knowing more of your environment I'm not sure there is an answer to your question.